# to get the text from image name using split using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

I have an image and i have sliced the image into 16 slices using `image_slicer`, and the images are named as `0804220001-5_01_01.png,0804220001-5_01_02.png,0804220001-5_01_03.png` and so on. Using `split` I need the text 01_01,01_02,..
I tried using split and rsplit but I am not getting the result. below is my code.

```
#img1 is the path of the image which is 
#Features/input/0804220001-5_02_04.png
name1 = img1.split('/')[-1]
patch = name1.rsplit('_')[1]
print(patch)
```

i am getting the output as **01** but I need the output as **01_01,01_02**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re.search` with `_(.*)\.` pattern :

```
import re

str = " 0804220001-5_02_04.png "
print(re.search('_(.*)\.', str).group(1))
```

which extracts `02_04` as output.

Answer (score 0):

We can try using `re.findall` here for a regex approach:

```
images = ["0804220001-5_01_01.png", "0804220001-5_01_02.png", "0804220001-5_01_03.png"]
# form single | delimeted string of all images
all_images = "|".join(images)
terms = re.findall(r'(\d+_\d+)\.png', all_images)
print(terms)
```

This prints:

```
['01_01', '01_02', '01_03']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

foo = 'some/path/0804220001-5_01_01.png'
print('_'.join(os.path.splitext(foo)[-2].split('_')[-2:]))
```

output

```
01_01
```

Of course you can make this a function

Answer (score 0):

In your case, if you want to stick to your method and without using os path or anything, you can just fix the rsplit() to split(). You can use split() to split. The below code meant, you split with '_' at maximum one time and starting from the left. Split() optional argument is how many times you want to split and it defaults to -1(infinite).

```
img1 = "Features/input/0804220001-5_02_04.png"
name1 = img1.split('/')[-1]
patch = name1.split('_', 1)[1] # this if you don't want the file name --> [:-4]

print(patch)
```